# Custom cell formatting that has alt code characters in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Context: I'm looping over cells in Range using two loops: one for rows (i) and the other for column (j) and looking up values (sales ratio that is 0 to 1) in a different table. The cell will be formatted into percentages and use this variable called `sales_thershold` that will be used to add an up arrow ↑ (>10) or down arrow ↓ (<0), or nothing (0-10) to the cell formatting. The following is what I tried for a given cell:

```
If sales_thershold > 10 Then
   Cells(i,j).NumberFormat = "0%" & "[" & ChrW(24) & sales_thershold & "]"
ElseIF sales_thershold < 0 Then
   Cells(i,j).NumberFormat = "0%" & "[" & ChrW(25) & (sales_thershold * -1) & "]"
Else
   Cells(i,j).NumberFormat = "0%" & "[" & sales_thershold & "]"
End If
```

I facing two issues:

1. The arrows - `ChrW(24)` or `ChrW(25)` are coming up as boxes (▯).
2. If the lookup value sales ratio is `0.6`. It shows up as `6%` rather than `60%`. Otherwise, if it is `0.61`, it shows up as `61%`

Some example outputs I want: 60%[↑15], 25[↓9], 32[0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets have a special meaning in the numberformat string so need to be escaped.  
`"\["`  and `"\]"`

Also `24` is NOT the code for an arrow. Should be something like `ChrW(8593)` for the up Arrow.

You other problem is also related to not properly escaping values which can be interpreted as formatting characters. In particular the `0` in `sales_thershold`.

Try format string such as:

```
= "0%\[" & ChrW(8593) & """" & sales_thershold & """" & "\]"
```

so as to isolate `sales_thershold` properly

Comment: Yes ```ChrW(8593)``` works for up arrow, and ```ChrW(8595)``` down arrow. But my second problem still persists.

Comment: @MJ That's because you are not escaping the digits in your `sales_thershold` variable. See my edit.

Comment: Is there a list where I can find codes for other symbols like the up arrow - ```ChrW(8595)```?

Comment: What happened when you tried an internet search engine? Didn't that work? What search terms did you use? I'm sure there are many lists out there.

Comment: I looked up "up arrow character code excel." I came across a website that said alt code 24 and 25 is for the up and down arrow.

Comment: @MJ You are not interpreting what you read correctly. That site is describing a method of generating the `8593` code, which is holding down the `alt` key while typing `24` on the numeric keypad.  `ChrW(24)` does not do that.